# Compound page numbers with single dash

Tags: biblatex

One of my references has page numbers like 12-2, where 12 is the section and 2 the page in this section. I would like to cite this with `citep[12-2]{xy}` but it is converted into a double-dash page range which results in `[1, pp. 12-2`].

Other solutions suggest something like `\citep[12{-}2]` or `\def\nbhyph{-\nobreak} \citep[12\nbhyph 2]` but both these solutions result in `[1, 12-2]` without the "p.".
I could fix this by adding the `p.` manually, i.e. `citep[p.~12{-}2]{xy}` but this looks like it breaks the design.

Is there a more generic solution to this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=ieee, natbib=true]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@Book{lamport94,
    author = "Leslie Lamport",
    title = "LaTeX: A Document Preparation System",
    year = 1994
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{bib}
\begin{document}

single dash \citep[12-2]{lamport94}

\def\nbhyph{-\nobreak}
nbhyph \citep[12\nbhyph 2]{lamport94}

bracelet dash \citep[12{-}2]{lamport94}

bracelet dash with manual "p." \citep[p.~12{-}2]{lamport94}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks the design"? The last version looks quite good to me.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: I feel like I shouldn't put the `p.` there manually. What if I want to change the `p.` to `page` for my whole document?

Comment: Instead of writing `p.` manually, it is nicer to use `\pno~` (or `\ppno~`), but of course that still is unnecessary work.

Answer (score 1):

Not that this is better than the alternatives already explored by the OP, but it *does* avoid placing the "p." manually.  It works by using an active `.` as a surrogate for a "page number dash", so that it isn't interpreted as a "page number range" which is the underlying problem being experienced.

The downside is that the `\citep` must be set in its own group with the `.` being made active prior to invocation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=ieee, natbib=true]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@Book{lamport94,
    author = "Leslie Lamport",
    title = "LaTeX: A Document Preparation System",
    year = 1994
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{bib}
\catcode`.=\active
\def.{-}%
\catcode`.=12
\begin{document}

active dot {\catcode`.=\active \citep[12.2]{lamport94}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could disable `-` being recognised as a range separator (you will want to treat it as a NumChar then) with

```
\DeclareRangeChars{~,;+/}
\DeclareNumChars*{-}
```

This however creates more problems than it solves, I believe, since now `\cite[12-34]{sigfridsson}` is not recognised as a range any more; you would have to write `\cite[12\bibrangedash 34]{sigfridsson}` or something along those lines.

---

Because I believe that pages such as `12-2` don't come up that often I would go with your solution of defining a new command for that hyphen

```
\def\pnhyph{-}
```

then in order to make sure that we still get the page prefix we need

```
\NumCheckSetup{\let\pnhyph\empty}
```

This just ignores this command when checking if we have a page number or not.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=ieee, natbib=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\def\pnhyph{-}
\NumCheckSetup{\let\pnhyph\empty}

\begin{document}
single dash \citep[12-2]{sigfridsson} \citep[12\bibrangedash 2]{sigfridsson}

\verb|\pnhyph| \citep[12\pnhyph 2]{sigfridsson}
  \citep[12\pnhyph 2--13\pnhyph 3]{sigfridsson}
  \citep[12\pnhyph 2-13\pnhyph 3]{sigfridsson}

bracelet dash with manual \verb|\pno| \citep[\pno~12{-}2]{sigfridsson}
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]