# BibLaTeX - old style number for page(s), and keeping "p." and "pp." in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, formatting

As mentioned in title, any way to make page number old-style, and keeping the pagination ("p." and "pp.")?

This is I have done so far:

My MWE code:

```
% !TEX program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@Article{Cormos2012,
  Title        = {Integrated assessment of IGCC power generation technology with carbon capture and storage (CCS)},
  Author       = {Cormos, C.},
  Journal      = {Energy},
  Year         = {2012},
  Number       = {1},
  Pages        = {434-445},
  Volume       = {42},
  ISBN         = {0360-5442},
  Publisher    = {Elsevier Ltd},
  Url          = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.energy.2012.03.025}
}

@Article{Mumford2015,
  Title        = {Review of solvent based carbon-dioxide capture technologies},
  Author       = {Mumford, Kathryn a. and Wu, Yue and Smith, Kathryn H. and Stevens, Geoffrey W.},
  Journal      = {Frontiers of Chemical Science and Engineering},
  Year         = {2015},
  Number       = {2},
  Pages        = {125-141},
  Volume       = {9},
  Doi          = {10.1007/s11705-015-1514-6},
  ISBN         = {2095-0179},
  Keywords     = {absorption,carbon capture,carbon dioxide,large scale,solvent},
  Url          = {http://link.springer.com/10.1007/s11705-015-1514-6}
}

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[%
    backend      = biber,
    style        = numeric-comp,
    firstinits   = true, 
    isbn         = false,
    doi          = true,
    url          = false,
    maxcitenames = 4,
    maxbibnames  = 4
]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{pages}{\mkpageprefix[pagination]{\oldstylenums{#1}}}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}
Here comes the 1st citation\autocite{Cormos2012} and the 2nd one\autocite{Mumford2015}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the page number of the first one [1] does not change at all, but the second one change successfully. Both of them losing "p." and "pp." that I intend to keep.

Sorry, I am new and have some "reputation" trouble to post the image.

Comment: I noticed that Ms. Mumford's second first name initial seems to be lowercase shouldn't it be `Author       = {Mumford, Kathryn A. and Wu, Yue and Smith, Kathryn H. and Stevens, Geoffrey W.},`?

Comment: @moewe Yes, silly copying mistakes of mine.

Answer (score 3):

With `\NumCheckSetup` you can ignore `\oldstylenums` when testing if the pages field is a number. (See also [Biblatex no printing “p.” when page number ends in some letters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121021/35864), [Compound page numbers with single dash](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/174780/35864) and [\DeclareNumChars and commands in page field](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150747/35864))

The safest solution is probably

```
\newcommand{\myosn}[1]{\ifpages{#1}{\oldstylenums{#1}}{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{pages}{\mkpageprefix[pagination]{\myosn{#1}}}
\NumCheckSetup{\renewcommand{\myosn}[1]{#1}}
```

---

Alternatively you can only ignore `\oldstylenums`

```
\DeclareFieldFormat*{pages}{\mkpageprefix[pagination]{\oldstylenums{#1}}}
\NumCheckSetup{\def\oldstylenums#1{#1}}
```

---

Another quick solution is to add `\oldstylenums` to the internal macro in charge of `\mkpageprefix`

```
\makeatletter
\protected\long\def\blx@mkpageprefix#1[#2]#3{%
  \ifnumeral{#3}
    {\bibstring{#1}\ppspace}
    {\ifnumerals{#3}
       {\bibstring{#1s}\ppspace}
       {\def\pno{\bibstring{#1}}%
        \def\ppno{\bibstring{#1s}}}}%
  \blx@mkpageprefix@i[#2]{\oldstylenums{#3}}}
\makeatother
```